# segmentation fault (core dumped) when adding this feature

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, null-pointer, function-definition

I try to add a function to an Code that already works. After adding my function, the code is still executed, but when I choose case 3, I get the error segmentation fault (core dumped)
I  get the segmentation fault (core dumped) error, if i choose case 3

Here is my Function to case 3:

```
typedef struct Note_
{
    int data;
    struct Note_ *next;
} Note;

Note *head= NULL;
int number= 0;


void deleteNote(int x){
    
 Note *t = head;
 Note *prev;

 if(t == NULL){
 printf("List already empty.\n");
 }
 while(t != NULL && t->data == x){
 head = t->next;
 free(t);
 t= head;
 printf("Note %d deleted.\n", x);
 }
 
 while(t != NULL){
 while(t != NULL && t->data != x){
 prev = t;
 t = t->next;
 }
 prev->next = t->next;
 free(t);
 t = prev->next;
 }
 
 }
```

Comment: Please one question at a time. If you get the syntax error, you can't get segmentation fault. So what is the real problem?

Comment: no i only get now the segmentation fault. Forget the first wuestion

Comment: Then please edit the question to contain only relevant information, including [mcve]

Comment: ok i do it already

Comment: There are missing elements  (the context of the function call, the `Note` structure ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
        prev->next = t->next;
        free(t);
        t = prev->next;
```

the pointer `t` can be equal to `NULL` after the preceding while loop.

```
    while(t != NULL && t->data != x)
    {
        prev = t;
        t = t->next;
    }
```

So using a null pointer to access memory like in this statement

```
         prev->next = t->next;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You need to check whether after the while loop the pointer `t` is not equal to `NULL`.

Comment: ok but i dont get now what i should change or write in my code

Comment: can anyone help

Comment: @adersat What is unclear with the phrase "You need to check whether after the while loop the pointer t is not equal to NULL." in my answer? Is it difficult to insert an if statement?

Comment: but I have to add the if statement between the two while loops or

Comment: @adersat after the inner loop check whether the pointer t is equal to NULL.